# Tooltip-annotated Python source code in Jupyter Notebook HTML output

Tags: jupyter-notebook, python-sphinx

My goal is to create high-quality Python code examples.

I am using Jupyter Notebooks for code examples in the notebook. Is it possible to have Jupyter notebook itself, or Sphinx documentation created from it using `nbsphinx` to have class and type documentation available as tooltips?

- User could hover mouse over the example code to see the class/type of variables
- The mouse over tooltip would contain the docstring (class description)
- Jupyter notebook seem to be able to pull this information in already when you are editing the notebooks
- Clicking variables in code examples would jump to the documentation of their class/type definition

Below is an example screenshot what a tooltip looks when mouse is hovered over notebook in PyCharm. Having such functionality available in the code examples and documentation would make documentation much more useful.

[image]

Comment: "Sphinx documentation created from it using nbsphinx to have class and type documentation available as tooltips". There's more current tools in this ecosystem. For example, [MyST - Markedly Structured Text - Parser](https://myst-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [the nbdev2 version of nbdev](https://nbdev.fast.ai/migrating.html), see [here](https://github.com/pydata/pydata-sphinx-theme/issues/1474) also. And I would suggest this would be better suited for [the Jupyter Discourse Forum](https://discourse.jupyter.org/) as it is rather open ended and more suited for an exchange.